# How Firebase Performance Monitoring intercepts outgoing http requests in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-performance

From firebase's [help doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/network-traces?platform=ios), it states

> For all app types, Performance Monitoring automatically collects a
> trace for each network request issued by your app, called an HTTP/S
> network request trace Performance Monitoring automatically collects
> metrics for network requests that use the following networking
> libraries: URLSession, URLConnection

How are they tracking the http requests automatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS, Firebase Performance Monitoring uses [method swizzling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53189296/807126) to effectively rewrite calls to `NSURLConnection` to its own implementation (which in turn calls back into the original iOS implementation). This allows the SDK to record what the app is doing for HTTP requests.